# Web client method downloadFileAsync displaying forbidden error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have been downloading file through this method for the past two years but now it is giving this forbidden error(403). This is the address : http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2014/JUL/fo04JUL2014bhav.csv.zip. And this is the code :

```
wcNseFut.DownloadFileAsync(uriNseFut, strFullFileName)
```

strFullFileName is the path to save the file. I have tried a lot but it is not resolved yet. Please help.
Full code :

```
 If CheckValidations() = True Then
            If CheckNet() Then
                Dim strFullFileName As String

                dtBhav = CDate(dtBhavcopyDate.Value)
                btnNseFuturesDownload.Enabled = False
                btnNseFuturesDownload.Text = "Downloading....."

                AddHandler wcNseFut.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wcNseFut_DownloadFileCompleted
                AddHandler wcNseFut.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf wcNseFut_DownloadProgressChanged

                MDIStockMIS.UStatusBar.Panels("Text").Text = ""
                MDIStockMIS.UStatusBar.Panels("Text").Text = "Downloading file ..........."

                ''-------- Download NSE future file
                ''-------- http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2014/APR/fo11APR2014bhav.csv.zip
                Dim uriNseFut As New Uri(NseFuturesFTPAddress(dtBhav))

                strFullFileName = ""
                strFullFileName = m_strPathEQ & "\" & BHAVCOPY_NSE_FO_FOLDER & ".zip"
                DeleteFile(strFullFileName, False)
                wcNseFut.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
                wcNseFut.DownloadFileAsync(uriNseFut, strFullFileName)
            End If
        Else
            ShowUltraMessage(Nothing, "Please select the path and enter a valid date.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                          MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, "", "", _
                          "Check conditions", "Stock MIS")
        End If
```

Comment: 403 forbidden means the website is not allowing you to download the file. Can you download the file from a web browser?  I am guessing the website is now blocking your app

Comment: yes I can download file from the browser.

Comment: Maybe set the user agent for the webclient so the website thinks it is a browser downloading the file. wcNseFut.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")

Comment: I added the header you told but now giving the error of forbidden 404

Comment: Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: I don't no about proxy server.

Comment: `wcNseFut.DownloadFileAsync(uriNseFut, strFullFileName)` this is not full code. Please provide full code to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: this is the full code :

Comment: full code given above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kentucker suggestion of adding user-agent to webclient header was very close to the solution. I just used fiddler to get the correct user-agent, added some network credentials and then it worked fine.